# "Slack integrations" and "Microsoft Teams integrations" in Settings lead to 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, 404-not-found, preferences, stack-overflow-for-teams

"Slack integrations" and "Microsoft Teams integrations" appear [in the Settings page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences) sidebar on every site, including here on Meta.SE. Both lead to 404 pages. Shouldn't these links only appear for those using Teams?

> [image]

Comment: Im experiencing a similar problem too, didnt think much of it at first till you asked!

Comment: Those two tool integrations are part of the [free tier](https://stackoverflow.co/teams/integrations/).

Comment: @bad_coder so? It's still available only for those who join Teams, most users will just get error, those are broken links.

Comment: Actually I think it only works on SO + you have teams. It 404s on MSE but not SO

Comment: @JourneymanGeek it's 404ing for me both on SO and here.

Comment: Ya, I have a teams account so they work on SO, they 404 here.

Comment: As mentioned above, these pages only work for users in Teams, so I think they should probably be removed from settings pages on all other sites (and possibly only be shown if the user is in a Team?).

Comment: @V2Blast yes, if something work only for users in Teams, that something should be shown only if the user is in Teams. :) (Otherwise it's just a broken link)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are correct; these integration items should not be displayed for sites that do not use Teams.

We have made an update to remove these items such that it is only available for those sites that use Teams.